# c++11: What's the use of a rvalue reference initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
int n = 1;
double&& rref = n;
```

Under what kind of scenario do we need to initialize a rvalue variable, given

- we can cast values to rvalues by move
- named variables are lvalue

?

EDIT:

I changed the example to double&& to make it compile.  The question remains, or even more relevant in my opinion.

Some background, I read on cppreference that "An rvalue may be used to initialize an rvalue reference, in which case the lifetime of the object identified by the rvalue is extended until the scope of the reference ends."  I don't quite understand the point of this statement.  Regardless whether it's a rvalue or not, we have to decide on whether to extend the lifetime of a variable, presumably returned from another function?

Comment: There's no such thing as an *rvalue variable*. *rvalue* is a value category of an *expression*. Variables of type *rvalue reference* have to be initialized in their definition like variables of type *lvalue reference*.

Comment: You can use rvalue reference variables to bind a temporary of a non-copyable, non-movable type. E.g. `struct ncm { ncm(ncm const&)=delete; ncm(ncm&&)=delete; }; ncm foo() { return {}; } ncm&& var = foo();`

Comment: N.B. the original code was `int&& rref = n;` which was ill-formed, as `n` is an lvalue and therefore cannot bind to an rvalue reference. The new version creates a temporary of type `double` for the conversion `int`->`double` and binds this temporary to the rvalue ref (well-formed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should in general avoid using rvalue-references.

I cannot think of a really *good* reason to use a local rvalue-reference. I can imagine one use case: extending the lifetime of a temporary while at the same time allowing read-write access to it (similar to binding to a `const T&`, but without the `const` restriction):

```
T f();
T && r = f();
// can use 'r' here for const/non-const access
```

While in this simple case you could argue that using a value is a better option, there are cases where the exact type returned by `f()` is not know, but you do know that it derives from a base, and in that case you could use the trick above to extend the lifetime:

```
template <typename T>
Derived<T> f(T const &);  // Derived<T> extends Base

Base && r = f(1);          // Extends lifetime
```

But even in that concrete use case, in C++11 there are better tools, like `auto`:

```
auto r = f(1);
```

Which will create a local variable of the concrete type returned by `f`. So it really does not enable any functionality.

Where rvalue-references are important are as arguments to functions, *when you **need** differentiate rvalue from lvalue*. If the behavior will be the same in both cases (i.e. you will copy) then just take the argument by value.

Quoting Eric Niebler's recent tweet:

> You should fear rvalue refs like one might fear God. They are powerful and good, but the fewer demands placed on them the better

Comment: Is the r in Base && r an xvalue?

Comment: @CandyChiu: No, it is an lvalue. Weird as it might be, an rvalue-reference is an lvalue, it just binds to rvalues. Well, the references are never ?value, an expression using the reference is.

Comment: xvalue is a simultaneous a rvalue and glvalue, so r looks like one to me.  It is confusing, better heed Eric's advice.

Comment: @CandyChiu: An *xvalue* is an *eXpiring* value, which can be either an rvalue, or an lvalue at the end of its lifetime under some circumstances (for example a local variable `a` in `return a;`). The reference `r` in the code binds to an *rvalue*, but uses of the reference are *lvalue* expressions as they refer to a real *object*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas How is this even possible? One of the first things you see in every tutorial about rvalue references to differentiate them from lvalue references is this; That lvalue references are addressable while rvalue references are not. So how is T&& r = ... legal? Are people actually talking about the = f(); being the rvalue reference? Does T&& r = ... become T& r during compilation?

Comment: @JoeManiaci: I am not sure I follow your question, how is *what* possible?  I think there could be different sources of misunderstanding, the first one is between *rvalue* and *rvalue-reference* (which interestingly enough is an *lvalue*!). Other than that, you cannot take the address of an *rvalue*, but you can *bind* a reference (`const` *lvalue-reference* or *rvalue-reference*) mainly because the language specification supports it

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas - So how would one read out loud T&& r = funccall(); ? r is a....     Also, how can you bind to an rvalue-reference, don't you need an address? Is it that funccall() has an address(you need somewhere to place the return value) but funccall() by itself won't store it anywhere? But once you bind it to something, then it's just a regular reference?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a shame to only link to an article without properly infringing copyright by copy-pasting the relevant section here, but [this article](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) explains why `&&` can be used as "Universal References".

In short, writing

```
auto&& //...
```

ensures maximum worry-free-ness, independent of the type `auto` represents here.

Comment: Universal references apply only to templates, the question has no templates anywhere. You might want to add the information as a comment, but this is not an answer.

Comment: *ensures maximum worry-free-ness* Does it? How is, as a local variable, that better than `auto` by itself?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: They apply to deduced types, which includes `auto` as well as templates.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Yes, initially the answer did not use `auto`. And yet the second comment still stands. I don't see any advantage of using an rvalue-reference there instead of plain `auto`